# Evaluate 0 in Handlebars

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, conditional-statements

I'm working with days of the week where Sunday is 0. Some ranges go from Monday - Sunday (day: 1, last: 0) and therefore it should display the range instead of the single day. But only get single dates. How do I evaluate if last == 0?

```
{{#if last}}
  <span>{{day day}} - {{day last}}</span>
{{else}}
  <span>{{day day}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I evaluate if last == 0?

the #unless helper would return true on a falsy value such as 0

```
//returns true if last is a falsy
{{#unless last}}
  <span>{{day day}} - {{day last}}</span>
{{else}}
  <span>{{day day}}</span>
{{/unless}}
```

as it can be null you can define a helper to test for a specific value, here is one i normally use when i want some logic in my templates above truthy or falsy

```js
var data = [
    {
    day: 1,
    last: null
    },
    {
    day: 2,
    last: 1
    },
    {
    day: 3,
    last: 0
    }

];

var source = $("#entry-template").html();


Handlebars.registerHelper('gte', function(target, condition, options) {
  if (target >= condition) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
var tempalte = Handlebars.compile(source);

$("body").append(tempalte(data));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{!-- as suggested by @undeletable --}}
 {{#each this}}<span>{{day}}  {{#gte last 0}} - {{last}} {{/gte}} </span><br/>{{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: This would be more smart: `<span>{{day day}}{{#unless last}} - {{day last}}{{/unless}}</span>`

Comment: @undeletable I concur that is smarter:)

Comment: But using this helper isn't correct if `last` is equal to any other falsy value.

Comment: @undeletable True looking at the question i assume last and day will be numbers from 0-6 but if this is not the case then patrick will need to be aware of this

Comment: According to my own practice, `last` can be not defined from the beginning, or its initial value can be `null`, and due to different reasons other value can be not set later.

Comment: Thanks! Values range from 0-7, should have all cases included.

Comment: @Patrick `should have all cases included` means it might not be a defined number?

Comment: @Quince: I can be null, or numbers from 0 - 7. Nothing apart from that.

Comment: in which case then you will need a specif helper to test for 0 and not a general falsy will update the answer

Comment: added an example using a helper, changed the logic slight to just show the raw value of day as wasn't sure what your day helper does but its the same thing esstentially

Comment: Made a slight modification to handle everything above 0 (greater than or equal to 0). Works fine, thanks!

Comment: so this will display when last is greater than or equal to 0, i thought from your question you want it only when last was 0? or am i misreading it?